# AWS S3 bucket logs to Elastic search service (AWS) through log stash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash

I set up log stash on EC2 Linux (AWS) and Elastic search service on AWS

and I have created one separate file (with input and output) under /etc/logstash/conf.d path

but I am not able to  logs in Kibana

and connection has been established between two nodes successfully
any suggestion to check where I am missing this?

Comment: Do you have data in elastic? Have you run some queries directly on that?

Comment: I could see "searchable documents: 4" in the AWS console, but don't know how to access them

Comment: input {
  s3 {
    #"access_key_id" => "your_access_key_id"
    #"secret_access_key" => "your_secret_access_key"
    #"region" => "us-east"
    "bucket" => "<my bucket name>"
    #"prefix" => "Logs"
    #"interval" => "10"
    #"additional_settings" => {
     # "force_path_style" => true
      #"follow_redirects" => false
                }
  }
}
 
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https:xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:443"]
    index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}

Comment: my config file looks like above one

Comment: When providing new information, you should update the question instead of using comments. And only post the relevant parts of the configuration, not parts that are commented. Also in such case, adding logstash logs to the question could be a good idea.